# CSS | Overflow child element with width 100%

Tags: html, css

### The Problem

First of all: [codepen](https://codepen.io/khegay/pen/MVGYjV)

body, html width and height = 100%

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I have parent div with width 100% and height 100% out of body, and body out of html

```
.p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Then:
I have 2 child elements with both height 100% and width 20% + 80% and overflow-x: scroll

```
.c1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background: red;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.c2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    background: blue;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

I do not understand why scroll is showing up?

Comment: because you specify it 3 times -->  `overflow-x: scroll;`

Comment: You're setting overflow to scroll what do you expect ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif but scroll should appear only when content of element is bigger than element

Comment: read the doc of the property then ... i have nothing to say more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `overflow: scroll;` to `overflow: auto`

Answer (score 0):

Remove, `overflow-x: scroll`

**`overflow-x: scroll` property always show the scrollbar even if all content fits and you cant scroll it.**

```css
body, html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.p {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: green;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
.c1 {
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 background: red;
 
}
.c2 {
 height: 100%;
 width: 80%;
 background: blue;

}
```

```html
<div class="p">
 <div class="c1"></div>
 <div class="c2"></div>
</div>
```

**Please Run the Above Snippet**

Comment: or simply remove it, it's useless

Comment: @TemaniAfif, but he needs scroll bar to appear from one of his comments

Comment: he's using reset css, check well his pen ... and no he don't want the scroll to appear